# Displaying unescaped strings in a Python 2.7 dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, escaping

Printing a string in Python prints the unescaped version of the string.  But if the string is a key or value in a dictionary, printing the dictionary prints the *escaped* version of the string.  Is there a straightforward way to display the dictionary with the strings unescaped?  Here is an example of the behavior that I'm talking about:

```
>>> thing = {'a' : '\d'}
>>> thing
{'a': '\\d'}
>>> print thing
{'a': '\\d'}
>>> print thing['a']
\d
```

Comment: Containers display contained strings (and anything else contained) using their *representation*; a value that can safely be pasted back into Python. That representation includes using escape codes for everything non-ASCII and not printable, *and* doubling the backslash to prevent it being interpreted as an escape sequence start.

Comment: Is there an alternate way to display containers, or is that something I'm going to have to implement myself?

Comment: You'll have to implement it yourself, I am afraid.